# Error due to Site.Master file - asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am receiving an error due to the Site.Master file. I have made numerous adjustments and still cannot get past this issue with the Site.Master file. Do I have the wrong specification perhaps? My code executes perfectly in Microsoft Visual Studios, however when I export the site files to the hosted servers this is where I run into issues.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
>
> Line 1365:            System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem
>
> Container; Line 1366:            System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl target;
>
> Line 1367:            `across-america.Models.Category Item;`
>
> line 83 "E:\server\USER\across-america\Site.Master"

The error is due to the following:

```
<asp:ListView ID="categoryList" ItemType="across-america.Models.Category" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetCategories">
```

I have modified the temType="across-america.Models.Category" to remove across-america but then I still get an error. Any advice???

C# code with error:

```
<div id="CategoryMenu" style="text-align: center">       
    <asp:ListView ID="categoryList" ItemType="Models.Category" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetCategories">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <b style="font-size: large; font-style: normal">
                <a href="/ProductList.aspx?id=<%#: Item.CategoryID %>">
                <%#: Item.CategoryName %>
                </a>
            </b>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate>  |  </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

Models Class in Category.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Product Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Site.Master Models Reference, towards the end of code:

```
using Models;
using across-america.Logic;

namespace across-america
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
        private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
        private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The code below helps to protect against XSRF attacks
            var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
            Guid requestCookieGuidValue;
            if (requestCookie != null && Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
            {
                // Use the Anti-XSRF token from the cookie
                _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;
                Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
            }
            else
            {
                // Generate a new Anti-XSRF token and save to the cookie
                _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

                var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
                };
                if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection)
                {
                    responseCookie.Secure = true;
                }
                Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
            }

            Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
        }

        protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Set Anti-XSRF token
                ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;
                ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                // Validate the Anti-XSRF token
                if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
                    || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] != (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
            {
                string cartStr = string.Format("Cart ({0})", usersShoppingCart.GetCount());
                cartCount.InnerText = cartStr;
            }
        }
        public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            var _db = new Models.ProductContext();
            IQueryable<Category> query = _db.Categories;
            return query;
        }
        protected void Unnamed_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is line 1365?

Comment: @DanielA.White There isn't even this many lines! There are only 100 lines!

Comment: I did some additional tweaking and updated the error I am now receiving. @DanielA.White

Comment: Please show us the class definition (or at least the declared namespace) for `Models.Category`

Comment: I have updated the code to display the category.cs page with models class definition. Please let me know if I can provide additional details. @DavidTansey

Comment: Is `Category.cs` in a class library project or is it in your web project?  You say that you: _'export the site files to the hosted servers'_ -- what tool(s) are using to do this?

Comment: It is just a class file. I created the site using the WingtipToys tutorial on asp.net site using Microsoft Visual Studios. Then I uploaded the site files into Filezilla just by dragging and dropping the directory into FZ. I have also updated the code to provide the class file for this page, but this error is due to the CategoryMenu portion which is on every page.